# Multiple Prefix Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How to use multi prefix in this code? I have tried various ways but nothing works.

```js
let prefix = [ 'e', 'E' ];
        if (message.guild) {
            client.prefixes.ensure(message.guild.id, { prefix: 'e' });
            let guildPrefix = client.prefixes.get(message.guild.id, "e");

            prefix = guildPrefix ? guildPrefix : 'e';
        }   
        
        if(!(message.content.startsWith(prefix[0])||message.content.startsWith(prefix[1]))) { return; }

        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
```

This is the code, its not work, i dont know why?
can u help me guys?
i use discord.js v13

Comment: `arrayOfPrefixes.some(p => message.content.startsWith(p))`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!(message.content.startsWith(prefix[0])||message.content.startsWith(prefix[1]))) { return; }
```

It will not start with an array, so you have to split the condition. However there might be a more elegant solution to this.

Edit: The elegant solution is in the comments.

Comment: sorry, its still doesn't work, can u help me ? i just add a new code

Comment: @AldiBoytons if it returns an error please, edit the question and add it. If it doesnt,  place `console.log("FlagX")` outside and inside each `if` statement to check where it fails to get in